# Let $f$ be a bounded, continuous function such that $f(t+17) = f(t)$ for all $t$

Tags: integration, functions, continuity, periodic-functions

> Let $f$ be a bounded, continuous function such that $f(t+17) = f(t)$ for all $t$. Show that for all $\alpha$, we have $$\int_0^{17} f(t) \,dt = \int_\alpha^{17+\alpha} f(t) \,dt$$

How can I solve this question?

Edit:
Can I take u = t + $\alpha$, t = u - $\alpha$, du = dt
$$\int_0^{17} f(t) \,dt = \int_\alpha^{17+\alpha} f(u-\alpha) \,du$$
Then how can I proceed?

Comment: Hint: u-substitution.

Comment: Or, fundamental theorem of calculus on $I(\alpha)$ where $I$ is the integral on the right.

Comment: @SeanRoberson what the u that I should take?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I didn't get your point how can I solve it with the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: Define the function $I(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ as

$$I(\alpha)=\int_\alpha^{\alpha+17}f(t)dt\ .$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$I'(\alpha) = f(\alpha+17)-f(\alpha)=0 $$

by the periodicity of $f$. So $I(\alpha)$ is constant and equal to $I(0)$

$$\int_\alpha^{\alpha+17}f(t)dt=I(\alpha)=I(0)=\int_0^{17} f(t)dt\ .$$

Method 2: Split the integral into three parts and make the substitution $t=s+17$ on the third as follows

$$\begin{align}\int_\alpha^{\alpha+17}f(t)dt &= \int_\alpha^{0}f(t)dt+\int_0^{17}f(t)dt+\int_{17}^{\alpha+17}f(t)dt\\
&= \int_\alpha^{0}f(t)dt+\int_0^{17}f(t)dt+\int_{0}^{\alpha}f(s+17)ds \\
&= \int_\alpha^{0}f(t)dt+\int_0^{17}f(t)dt +\int_{0}^{\alpha}f(s)ds\\
&= \int_\alpha^{0}f(t)dt+\int_0^{17}f(t)dt-\int_{\alpha}^{0}f(s)ds \\
&= \int_0^{17}f(t)dt\ .\end{align}$$

Comment: The second proof is more general as it doesn't assume continuity of f

Comment: Before last step how could you cancel the first integral with the last integral and one is t one is s?

Comment: The letter (or symbol) used for the integration variable doesn't change the value of the definite integral. If you feel more comfortable makes the substitution $t=s$ in the final integral before cancelling.